# Undo scaffolding in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scaffolding

Is there any way to 'undo' the effects of a scaffold command in Rails?

Answer (score 816, accepted):

**First**, if you have already run the migrations generated by the `scaffold` command, you have to perform a rollback first.

```
rake db:rollback
```

You can create scaffolding using:

```
rails generate scaffold MyFoo
```

(or similar), and **you can destroy/undo** it using

```
rails destroy scaffold MyFoo
```

That will delete all the files created by `generate`, but not any additional changes you may have made manually.

Comment: dont forget to `rake db:rollback` before you destroy your scaffold. This will destroy/drop the table if there is no other migration except the scaffold's migration before it.

Comment: In some cases there are still leftover files that were not deleted from the scaffold. Check your version control, e.g. `git status` and/or `git diff`, to see if the destroy command missed anything.

Comment: If you ran rake db:migrate did some other migrations after that then it makes sense to create a migration to destroy the table before "destroying" the scaffold. so do something like
rails g migration DropMyFoos
and then open the migration file and add code for dropping the table.
Run this migration and then run the destroy scaffold.

Comment: Also keep in mind that it will remove the view folder for my_foo, even if you have extra files there.

Answer (score 168):

Rishav Rastogi is right, and with rails 3.0 or higher its:

```
rails generate scaffold ...
```

```
rails destroy scaffold ...
```

Comment: @femi The table was made with rake. The best way to remove it is running `rake db:rollback` before `rails destroy scaffold` or if it is not the last one you did rake `db:migrate:down VERSION=20080906120000` you can find the number before its name in db/migrate

Answer (score 40):

You can undo whatever you did with

```
rails generate xxx
```

By

```
rails destroy xxx
```

For example this applies generators to migration, scaffold, model...etc

Answer (score 13):

If you just want to see the files a generator will create you can pass the generator --pretend or -p option.

Answer (score 10):

Best way is :

```
destroy rake db:  rake db:rollback
```

For Scaffold:

```
rails destroy scaffold Name_of_script
```

Answer (score 9):

for first time, you can check you database migration if you have generate scaffold.
you must destroy them to clean up your database

```
rake db:rollback
```

then

```
rails d scaffold
```

Answer (score 8):

```
rails d scaffold <scaffoldname>
```

Also, make sure you undo the migration you made either by rollback or to a particular version.

Answer (score 4):

To generate scaffolding :

```
rails generate scaffold xyz
```

To revert scaffolding :

```
rails destroy scaffold xyz
```

Answer (score 4):

Rails destroy name

```
rake db:rollback
```

Comment: first rollback (if you migrated), then destroy the scaffold

Answer (score 3):

For generating scaffold in rails -

```
rails generate scaffold MODEL_GOES_HERE
```

For undo scaffold in rails -

```
rails destroy scaffold MODEL_GOES_HERE
```

Comment: Also shortcuts `rails g` and `rails d`.

Answer (score 2):

you need to roll back migrations too after destroying scaffold too

```
rails destroy scaffold 'scaffoldname'
rake db:rollback
```

Answer (score 2):

So, Process you should follow to undo scaffolding in rails 4. Run Command as below:

1. `rails d scaffold FooBar`
2. `rake db:rollback` if you_had_run_`rake db:migrate` after creating above scaffold?

That's it!

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
rails d scaffold MODEL_NAME

rake db:rollback
```

Answer (score 2):

Recommend rollback First ,type in your Terminal.

```
rake db:rollback
```

Add destroy scaffold (the 'd' stands for 'destroy')

```
rails d scaffold name_of_scaffold
```

Enjoy your code.

Answer (score 2):

To generate:

```
rails g scaffold post
rake db:migrate
```

To delete:

```
rake db:rollback
rails d scaffold post
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to rollback the migrations first by doing rake db:rollback if any
And then destroy the scaffold by

```
rails d scaffold foo
```

Answer (score 1):

First you will have to do the **rake db:rollback** for destroy the table
if you have already run **rake db:migrate** and then you can run

**rails d scaffold Model**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `scaffold` itself and all the things that amalgamate it.

The `destroy` command is the opposite of `generate` and will undo one. Just pass it the name the same way did with `generate` and it'll be scrubbed from your project:

```
rails generate scaffold posts title:string content:text
rails destroy scaffold posts title:string content:text
```

Answer (score 1):

To generate the scaffold:

```
rails generate scaffold abc
```

To revert this scaffold:

```
rails destroy scaffold abc
```

If you have run the migration for it just rollback

```
rake db:rollback STEP=1
```

Answer (score 1):

provider another solution based on git

start a new project

```
rails new project_name
cd project_name
```

initialize git

```
git init
git commit -m "initial commit"
```

create a scaffold

```
rails g scaffold MyScaffold
rake db:migrate
```

rollback the scaffold

```
rake db:rollback
git reset --hard
git clean -f -d
```

Answer (score 1):

> rails [option]  scaffold  scaffold_name

**Option**

```
g    generate
d    destroy
```

If you do

```
rails g  scaffold myFoo
```

Then reverse it back using

```
rails d scaffold MyFoo
```

Answer (score 0):

When we generate scaffold, following files will be created:

Command: `rails generate scaffold Game`

Files created:

```
>       invoke  active_record
>       create    db/migrate/20160905064128_create_games.rb
>       create    app/models/game.rb
>       invoke    test_unit
>       create      test/models/game_test.rb
>       create      test/fixtures/games.yml
>       invoke  resource_route
>        route    resources :games
>       invoke  inherited_resources_controller
>       create    app/controllers/games_controller.rb
>       invoke    erb
>       create      app/views/games
>       create      app/views/games/index.html.erb
>       create      app/views/games/edit.html.erb
>       create      app/views/games/show.html.erb
>       create      app/views/games/new.html.erb
>       create      app/views/games/_form.html.erb
>       invoke    test_unit
>       create      test/controllers/games_controller_test.rb
>       invoke    helper
>       create      app/helpers/games_helper.rb
>       invoke      test_unit
>       create        test/helpers/games_helper_test.rb
>       invoke    jbuilder
>       create      app/views/games/index.json.jbuilder
>       create      app/views/games/show.json.jbuilder
>       invoke  assets
>       invoke    coffee
>       create      app/assets/javascripts/games.js.coffee
>       invoke    scss
>       create      app/assets/stylesheets/games.css.scss
>       invoke  scss
>       create    app/assets/stylesheets/scaffolds.css.scss
```

If we have run the migration after this then we have to rollback the migration first as the deletion of scaffold will remove the migration file too and we will not able to revert that migration.

Incase we have run the migration:

```
rake db:rollback
```

and after this we can safely remove the scaffold by this commad.

```
rails d scaffold Game
```

This command will remove all the files created by the scaffold in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you run `rails g`, you can reverse it by running `rails d` (destroy) to remove what you've generated. If you have already run `rake db:migrate`, you will need to run `rake db:rollback` before destroying :)

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1:** If you run only this command to generate scaffold -

```
rails generate scaffold MODEL_NAME FIELD_NAME:DATATYPE

Ex - rails generate scaffold User name:string address:text
```

but till now you did not run any command for migration like

```
rake db:migrate
```

then you should need to run only this command like -

```
rails destroy scaffold User name:string address:text
```

**Case 2:** If you already run(Scaffold and Migration) by below commands like -

```
rails generate scaffold User name:string address:text

rake db:migrate
```

Then you should need to run first rollback migration command then destroy scaffold like below -

```
rake db:rollback

rails destroy scaffold User name:string address:text
```

So In this manner, we can undo scaffolding. Also we can use **d** for **destroy** and **g** for **generate** as a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

```
rails g scaffold MyFoo
```

for generating and

```
rails d scaffold MyFoo
```

for removing

Comment: And no need to mention the attributes, it that correct? Thanks