# How to delete model and scaffolding in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, scaffolding

How can I delete an existing model and scaffolding in ruby on rails 3?

Can I just nuke the folders?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/963420/368167)

Answer (score 24):

```
rails destroy scaffold MyScaffold
```