# Rails - Routing error when destroying session path in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I created a simple rails app and implemented devise on it, I added the login/register feature and it works fine. But when I add the "log out" feature, it gives me a `Routing Error` that `No route matches [GET] "/ideas/sign_out"`

Here is what I implemented:

```
<% unless idea_signed_in? %>
    <li><a href="#">Explore</a></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Sign in", new_idea_session_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Share an idea", new_idea_registration_path %></li>
<% else %>
    <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Explore</a></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_idea_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
<% end %>
```

Even tried it with `:method => :delete` but still nothing. I `ran rake` routes and my routes are valid:

`destroy_idea_session_path  DELETE  /ideas/sign_out(.:format)   devise/sessions#destroy`

I added `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>` to my application.html.erb but still no luck.

My routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :ideas
  root 'welcome#index'

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `devise_for :ideas` to `devise_for :ideas, sign_out_via [:delete]`

It seems your controller is sending a get request instead of a delete request. Make sure you have Javascript enabled on whatever device you are using to test - the request falls back to GET if JS is not enabled.

EDIT: Make sure you find out what request your link is sending.

If all else fails, go to your Devise config file and change the line
`config.sign_out_via = :delete` to `config.sign_out_via = :get` and remove `, sign_out_via [:delete]` from your routes file.

Answer (score 2):

You know the problem already -

> No route matches `[GET] "/ideas/sign_out"`

This means that you're trying to link to the `logout` link using the `:get` method.

The main cause of this is to forget to put the `method: :delete` switch in your `link_to` reference. To ensure this is not the problem, you can use the following:

```
<%= link_to "Logout", destroy_idea_session_path, method: :delete %>
```

---

**JQuery**

If your link is implemented like this, which it seems to be, the next potential issue is that you **don't have jquery** loaded in your views.

[Rails delete method it doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21739122/rails-delete-method-it-doesnt-work)

The `delete` verb [actually isn't supported by most browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465919/rails-link-to-method-geting-when-it-should-delete), and as such, Rails uses jquery to modify the HTML to pass the `delete` switch as part of the link's `data` attributes.

Nominally, you need to ensure that you have JQuery loaded in your views & layout:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js.erb
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

This will ensure JQuery is loaded, and your application can handle the `DELETE` method.